# How to get widget from other widget , when findChild dosnt work , using promoted class

Tags: qt, widget

i have some simple hierarchy of widgets
looks something like this :

```
MainWindow->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(423, 479);
        MainWindow->setLayoutDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);
        MainWindow->setLocale(QLocale(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates));
        centralwidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralwidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralwidget"));
        horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(centralwidget);
        horizontalLayout->setSpacing(0);
        horizontalLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"));
        StreamViewWidget = new StreamView(centralwidget);
        StreamViewWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("StreamViewWidget"));
        horizontalLayout_2 = new QHBoxLayout(StreamViewWidget);
        horizontalLayout_2->setSpacing(0);
        horizontalLayout_2->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        horizontalLayout_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"));
        streamList = new StreamList(StreamViewWidget);
        streamList->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("streamList"));
        streamList->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(171, 251, 255);"));

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(streamList);


        horizontalLayout->addWidget(StreamViewWidget);

        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);
        menubar = new QMenuBar(MainWindow);
        menubar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menubar"));
        menubar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 423, 22));
        MainWindow->setMenuBar(menubar);
        statusbar = new QStatusBar(MainWindow);
        statusbar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusbar"));
        MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusbar);
```

now StreamViewWidget and streamList; are promoted , and i have there class
now from StreamViewWidget i want get access to streamList.
so i try to do this but it fails and im getting empty result .

```
StreamView::StreamView(QWidget *parent) :QWidget(parent)
{
 pStreamList = this->findChild<StreamList*>("streamList");
 QList<StreamList *> widgets = this->findChildren<StreamList *>("streamList");

}
```

also when i do in StreamView  QObject::dumpObjectTree() 
im getting : so i guess its not a child of  StreamView , but how can i get the streamList?

```
QWidget::centralwidget 
    QHBoxLayout::horizontalLayout 
    StreamView::
```

any idea what im doing wrong here ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(streamList);
```

the `horizontalLayout2` becomes the parent of `streamList`.  The parent of `horizontalLayout2` is `StreamViewWidget`, and `StreamViewWidget` is NOT the parent of `streamList`.  Does that makes sense?

But all that is besides the point.  The reason why it's not working is probably because you are trying to find the child of a widget that doesn't exist yet.  You are in the constructor of `StreamView`, remember?